# Click event on select with single option (Firefox) doen't work

Tags: javascript, firefox

I made a search tag interface, so I need to put my found tags like **option** in **select**. Then I wait user click (bubble up) on option and add this tag to groups of tags which will send to server. Why doesn't it work in FF? I know workaround solution to use the `mousedown` event instead of the `click` event, but I want to understand the logic, maybe it's  a bug and I need to report it to the  FF developers. By the way, everything works well when I add a few options, I think it is somehow related to the fact that by default 1 option is always select = true.

[Codepen sandbox](https://codepen.io/sergeyruskov/pen/GMgYKz?editors=1010)

```js
document.querySelector("#b").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(1);
});
```

```html
<select name="a" id="b">
  <option value="one">one</option>
</select>
```